# Android's Wallpapermanager in Flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter, wallpaper

I am writing an app for Android in Flutter that sets the user's wallpaper. I am having trouble finding how to do this, as Flutter is made to compile to both iOS and Android apps, and iOS doesn't allow apps to set a wallpaper. In Android, one can use the [WallpaperManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/WallpaperManager.html). Is there some way I can call this in Flutter, or is there some equivalent? I don't mind losing iOS compatibility, I just want it to work on Android.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, flutter has [`platform-channel`](https://flutter.io/platform-channels/) which allows you to call native code via flutter.

You can take a look at [this](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/tree/master/examples/platform_channel) flutter example that shows how to implement a platform channel in flutter.

Hope that helps!